# How can I show a macro as text?

Tags: macros, verbatim

Say I want to make a file which has as text `\documentclass{article}` I found out I can do it like this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
  \begin{verbatim}
    \documentclass{article}
  \end{verbatim}
\end{document}
```

That's fine. But what if I want to have as text `\begin{verbatim}` and `\end{verbatim}`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use the [`fancyvrb`](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/fancyvrb) package. This adds some nice features to the verbatim environment. Among other things it defines an environment `Verbatim` in which you can write `\end{verbatim}` since it won't match the `\begin{Verbatim}`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fancyvrb}
\begin{document}
  \begin{Verbatim}
      \begin{verbatim}      
        text        
      \end{verbatim}
  \end{Verbatim}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 6):

Define a new verbatim environment with different delimitation strings:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{verbatim}
\newenvironment{xverbatim}{\verbatim}{\endverbatim}

\begin{document}

\begin{verbatim}
\documentclass{article}
\end{verbatim}

\begin{xverbatim}
\begin{verbatim}
\documentclass{article}
\end{verbatim}
\end{xverbatim}

\end{document}
```

Remember also that verbatim environments respect code indentation, so your code

```
  \begin{verbatim}
    \documentclass{article}
  \end{verbatim}
```

will result in *four* spaces in front of `\documentclass{article}`.